# Как заставить персонажа смотреть в определенном направлении при респавне?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется вот такой простой код для респавна, однако если добавить функцию для персонажа *lookat*, то тогда при респавне происходит неприятная ситуация с тем, что камера накреняется из-за чего кажется что персонаж стоит под наклоном в сторону спавна.

```
public CharacterController player;
public GameObject respawn;
public Transform target;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        player.transform.position = respawn.transform.position;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать transform.[rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)

Пример:

```
public CharacterController player;
public GameObject respawn;
public Transform target;

[SerializeField] private Vector3 _rotation;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    player.transform.position = respawn.transform.position;
    player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(_rotation);
}
```